# React Native sort() in Flatlist with Objects dont work

Tags: javascript, react-native, sorting, object

im currently working on a school project and I need to sort the data by the Distance because the person that is at nearest. I tried to use the sort() function on the array but it wont work and I dont know why.

```
 <FlatList
                            data={this.state.teachers.sort((a,b) => {return a.dis - b.dis})}
                            keyExtractor={item => item.ID}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                                return <View style={styles.cardDesign}>

                                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', textTransform: 'capitalize', fontSize: 20, alignContent: "center", textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: '3%' }}>{item.fach}</Text>
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, alignItems: "center", textAlign: 'center', paddingBottom: '1%' }}>{item.firstname} {item.name}</Text>
                                    <Image  source={{ uri: item.picture}} style={{ flex: 100, resizeMode: 'contain', height: 200, width: "100%", paddingBottom: '5%' }} />
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, alignItems: "center", textAlign: 'center', paddingBottom: '1%' }}>{item.loan} € pro Stunde</Text>
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, alignItems: "center", textAlign: 'center', paddingBottom: '3%' }}>{item.distance} KM entfernt</Text>
                                    <View style={styles.contactButtonContainerStyle}>
                                    </View>
                                </View>;

                            }}
                        />
```

And here is where the Data is pushed into the array

```
this.setState({
                        teacher_lat: responseJson[i].latitude,
                    })

                    this.setState({
                        teacher_lon: responseJson[i].longitude,
                    })

                    var NotfachString = mathe + deutsch + englisch + politik + chemie + physik + "";
                    var fachString = NotfachString.substring(1);

                    var dis = getPreciseDistance(
                        { latitude: this.state.teacher_lat, longitude: this.state.teacher_lon },
                        { latitude: this.state.latitude, longitude: this.state.longitude },
                    );

                    dis = dis / 1000;


                    if (responseJson[i].ID != firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
                        if (subjectArray.length == 1) {
                            if (teacherFachID.includes(subjectArray[0].fachID) == true) {
                                if (this.state.entferung >= dis) {
                                    var dis = dis.toFixed(1);
                                    teachersArray.push({
                                        id: responseJson[i].ID,
                                        firstname: responseJson[i].firstname,
                                        name: responseJson[i].name,
                                        email: responseJson[i].email,
                                        gender: responseJson[i].gender,
                                        fach: fachString,
                                        distance: dis,
                                        loan: responseJson[i].loan,
                                        picture: responseJson[i].picture,
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }

                this.setState({
                    teachers: teachersArray,
                    isVisible: false,
                })
```

Thanks for everyone who can help

Answer (score 0):

The sort function needs to return one of the following: `-1`, `0`, or `1`.

I believe your sort function returns values that can be much higher or lower.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)